# How to limit a model to create one record per day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Business logic: A user can only create one entry for a journal per day. Before an entry can be created, it must query the records to determine if an entry has already been created for today.

I was looking for advice on the best way to approach this. I had a few ideas how to implement it on the client-side, but I'd really like to have validation on the model layer instead. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @vee Thanks. I just added the Rails version.

Comment: Also, mention what orm you use, because for Mongoid it will be different.

Comment: @zishe Thanks. I just added the ORM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a unique index on the journal table:

```
add_index :journal_entries, [:user_id, :created_on], unique: true
```

Then only one record with given user_id and date can be created and the database will raise an exception if this is violated. Note that `created_on` must be a `date` column, not `datetime`.

This is the only way to make it 100% sure that you don't get duplicates without explicit exclusive lock on the table.

Comment: This isn't true that this is the only 100% way. Active record `save` method is wrapped in atomic transaction, hence it can be achieved with simple validation as well.

Comment: @BroiSatse: Incorrect, the transaction doesn't help you at all. Pushing the logic into the database is the only way.

Comment: mu is too short could you please explains more details in "transaction doesn't help you at all"